# How to let osascript not build applescript code which will not hit at runtime?

Tags: applescript

We have a script to send email using `Microsoft outlook` or `Apple mail` application. It will dynamically load the default email from system preference (maybe user input also), and using it to decide which mail client to use.

So the code is as following:

```
if (mailClientStr contains "outlook")
   tell application id "com.microsoft.outlook" 
   -- <<< there will be error if there is no outlook installed 
   -- <<< even else branch will be run.
      ...
   end tell
else
   tell application id "com.apple.mail"
      ...
   end tell
end if
```

On an machine which doesn't have outlook installed, and the `mailClientStr` will be "com.apple.mail", but this script cannot be run by `osascript`

It complains `Can’t get application id "com.microsoft.outlook"` even the first branch will not be executed. My understanding is `osascript` will need to access Outlook apple script interface when load and compile this script (before run it).

I can separate the outlook related code into a separate script, but because there is a lot of data to passing, it will be complex, so I don't want this workaround.
So does there any solution from the apple script language side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the AppleScript Language Guide:

```
Entering Script Information in Raw Format

You can enter double angle brackets, or chevrons («»), directly into a script by typing Option-Backslash and Shift-Option-Backslash. You might want to do this if you’re working on a script that needs to use terminology that isn’t available on your current machine—for example, if you’re working at home and don’t have the latest dictionary for a scriptable application you are developing, but you know the codes for a supported term.

You can also use AppleScript to display the underlying codes for a script, using the following steps:

    Create a script using standard terms compiled against an available application or scripting addition.

    Save the script as text and quit Script Editor.

    Remove the application or scripting addition from the computer.

    Open the script again and compile it.

    When AppleScript asks you to locate the application or scripting addition, cancel the dialog.

Script Editor can compile the script, but displays chevron format for any terms that rely on a missing dictionary
```